# ¿Cómo puedo dar estilos a los elementos generados por un script?

Tags: css

Soy incapaz de aplicar estilos a los elementos que se generan con un `<script>`. Es para centrar un anuncio y hacerlo responsivo para que se muestre bien en móviles.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var uri = 'https://impes.tradedoubler.com/imp?type(iframe)g(23167128)a(2940467)' + new String (Math.random()).substring (2, 11);
        document.write('<iframe src="'+uri +'" width="468" height="60" frameborder="0" border="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>');
</script>
```

Este `<script>` genera entre otros elementos, un anchor que contiene la etiqueta `<img>` y que necesito darle estilos.

¿Cómo puedo centrarlo para cualquier dispositivo?

Comment: me puedes comentar que tipo de estilo quieres darle para que tenga mas omenos una idea como puedo ayudarte

Comment: Lo único que podrás con CSS es darle estilos al cuadro del iframe, no al contenido dentro del mismo, es decir.. podrás darle un tamaño..bordes, sombras a la caja.. pero no darle estilos al contenido.

Answer (score 0):

No puedes interactuar  con un iframe, es un sitio externo. El "problema" no es el Javascript, es el iframe. No importa como lo insertes esta trayendo la  informacion desde el otro sitio web